# How to merge (mosaic) images that have some similar parts in their file names in R

Tags: r, modis, rgdal

I have multiple GeoTIFF files each representing a single tile of MOD13A3 NDVI data. My study area is covered by 2 tiles and I have a time series spanning 60 months.
I want to mosaic(merge) every two tiles that have same capture year and month (coded into their file names).
How do I do that in R?

example file names:

```
"MOD13A3.A2000122.h20v09.006.2015137094939.tif"
"MOD13A3.A2000122.h21v09.006.2015137094940.tif"
"MOD13A3.A2000153.h20v09.006.2015138073415.tif"
"MOD13A3.A2000153.h21v09.006.2015138073637.tif"
"MOD13A3.A2000183.h20v09.006.2015138080555.tif"
"MOD13A3.A2000183.h21v09.006.2015138080549.tif"
"MOD13A3.A2000214.h20v09.006.2015138080545.tif"
"MOD13A3.A2000214.h21v09.006.2015138080533.tif"
"MOD13A3.A2000245.h20v09.006.2015139074702.tif"
"MOD13A3.A2000245.h21v09.006.2015139075852.tif"
"MOD13A3.A2000275.h20v09.006.2015139084458.tif"
"MOD13A3.A2000275.h21v09.006.2015139084957.tif"
```

I want to be able to run a function like

```
merge("MOD13A3.A2000122.h20v09.006.2015137094939.tif","MOD13A3.A2000122.h21v09.006.2015137094940.tif", filename = 2000122.tif)
```

and do that in an automated way.

Comment: Do you know how to read these into R? EG using the `raster` or `terra` package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work. I don't have your imagery, so I wasn't able to test it all the way through. If you're not using tidyverse, you can probably rewrite the date extraction in base R.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(raster)

#Simple example
filenames <- data.frame(name = c("MOD13A3.A2000122.h20v09.006.2015137094939.tif",
                                 "MOD13A3.A2000122.h21v09.006.2015137094940.tif",
                                 "MOD13A3.A2000153.h20v09.006.2015138073415.tif",
                                 "MOD13A3.A2000153.h21v09.006.2015138073637.tif"))

##Extract dates
filenames <- filenames %>% 
  mutate(date = substr(name, 10, 16)) %>% 
  mutate(date_posix = as.POSIXlt(date, format = "%Y%j")) %>% 
  mutate(year = year(date_posix), month = month(date_posix))

#Get unique combinations of dates
unique_dates <- unique(filenames[c('year', 'month')])

#Merge all images with a unique combination of year/month
for(i in 1:nrow(unique_dates)){
  
  selected_year <- unique_dates[i, 'year']
  selected_month <- unique_dates[i, 'month']

  selected_files <- filter(filenames, year == selected_year, month == selected_month) %>% 
    pull(name) %>% 
    as.list()
  
  mosaic <- do.call(raster::merge, selected_files)
  
  writeRaster(mosaic, filename = paste0("mosaic", selected_year, selected_month), format = "GTiff")
}
```

Comment: This works like a charm. I only had to change the "month" to "day" and I didn't even have to use Lubridate. I just pulled 'Year" and 'Day' as text.

Comment: I've the same rasters however, '  mosaic <- do.call(raster::merge, selected_files)' line creating error on 4 rasters when I explore them as list then it show different resolutions, dimmensions how can I modify above code for that?